# Graphene-Django: Would like to use graphene.ObjectType for custom query

Tags: django, graphene-python

I currently have a working query that is in this form:

```html
class Query(graphene.AbstractType):
algorithms = graphene.String(id=graphene.String())


def resolve_algorithms(self, args, context, info):

  # Much code here that goes to external server to get data

  algorithms = {}  # Instantiate dictionary

  # Code here to populate this dictionary

  return algorithms
```

While this does work, it's a kludge because I'm forcing the dictionary object to be returned as a string.  I've looked around for articles to show me how to change the type to graphene.ObjectType() but with no success.

Might someone know how?

Robert

Comment: If you include a sample or mock of your code to populate the dictionary it may help people answer the question. Is it nested, does it include other data types (lists, scalars)? And how did you attempt to change the type to `graphene.ObjectType`? Any links to those articles?

Comment: "algorithms" could be any kind of object.  For example, it might be as simple as having properties "id", "name", "description".  The point is that it's a representation of data coming from an external server that I wish to pass back as an object, not a string.  But when I do this:

    algorithms = graphene.Object(id=graphene.String())

I get an error.  I'm asking why this is wrong and how do I solve it?

Comment: Ok, I'm afraid I can't help you because I started playing with graphene a couple of days ago. That said, if it's a variable structure I don't think it's such a kludge to serialize it somehow and return it as a string.